# Migrating Integration Runtime in Azure

Tags: azure, runtime, integration, azure-data-factory

I have an existing Integration Runtime setup for Data Factory v1. Now I want to move it to another Data Factory, which is **v2**. However, I do not have access to the server, where the existing Integration Runtime is hosted. 
So my question is: Is it somehow possible to migrate the runtime from DFv1 to DFv2 without modifying the server? 
I tried copying the .json File of the Integration Runtime to a blank one in v2, but it would always fail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF v1 and ADF v2 are using different app model, there is no migration tool between ADF v1 gateway and ADF v2 integration runtime.

On the other hand, v1 gateway has no auto update function, there is no way to upgrade gateway to integration runtime without access to the host machine.

You can create v2 integration runtime under the v2 data factory with same name, however you will need to get access to the host server eventually, or setup another host machine.